# How to Track Android app downloads from various sources

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I have my app on google play and i want to start several campaigns. They will charge me for each  download so i want to track how many downloads are from which campaigns. I have already integrated google analytics do i need any other third party tracking tool to achieve this.

Comment: If you  get your answer please accept the given answer.

Comment: @MrNice sure i will..

Answer (score 3):

For measuring your download from different source google provides the **Google Play Campaign Measurement**. By using this you will be see which campaigns and traffic sources are sending users to download your app from the Google Play Store.

There is also so many third party API like [This](http://developers.mobileapptracking.com/android-sdk/) which allow to do the same.

Comment: I guess that's not what he's asking for, he's talking about real downloads not just redirections to the Google Play page, cause "practically" it has nothing to do with the real downloads, a lot of people click ads by mistake and go back immediately

Comment: I didn't propose an answer

Comment: Please read my ans i also given the link for real time tracking also..http://developers.mobileapptracking.com/android-sdk/

Comment: Ok sorry, for that you're right, Voting up your answer, and it should be accepted as well I guess